# Test Blank CD/DVD?

Tags: dvd, cd, testing

How would I test a blank CD/DVD + R to see if it's good.

I have a blank DVD that has a few light scratches on it and I want to see if it is able to burn a home movie onto it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot check a blank CD/DVD for errors other than having a closer look at the disc itself.